Скорость openVPN разнится от клиента к серверу и наоборот
Есть сервер openVPN (udp) и клиент до него, физический канал между ними 100мбит(тесты инета показывают полный канал в обе стороны), при тесте через ipref если сервером ipref выступает сервер openVPN получаю 87mbit, а если сервером ipref выступает клиент vpn то получаю 25мбит, при этом первый пакет ipref обычно уходит со скоростью ~40мбит, и сразу скорость падает и остальные идут 20-30мбит.
Что делал: выставлял разный кеш(125, 256, 512, 1024), как на стороне клиента так и сервера, не помогло, MTU на обоих концах 1500, проверял загрузку cpu при передаче данных - проц не загружен вообще.
Для теста ещё поставил клиентом машину в локальной сети с сервером, протестил - если сервером ipref выступает сервер openVPN получаю 282мбита, если сервером ipref выступает клиент vpn то получаю 97мбит. Также протестил переключив vpn на TCP - картина аналогична, ~80мбит в одну и те же 25мбит в другую.
UPD: поднял Wireguard вместо openVPN - ситуация ровно та же: если сервер ipref сервер VPN - 90мбит, обратно - 25мбит. Получается дело вряд-ли в протоколе vpn, провайдер, роутер у клиента, или с машиной клиента что-то не так(((
Конфиги: все машины на windows server 2019, роутеры перед обоими стоят микроты, сервер получается находится за NAT'ом для внешней машины.
Конфиг сервера:
port 1195
proto udp4
dev tun
ca "C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt"
key "C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key"
dh "C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"
server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
duplicate-cn
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
tls-auth "C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ta.key" 0
cipher AES-256-GCM
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
status "C:\\OpenVPN\\log\\status.log"
log "C:\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 3
mute 20
windows-driver wintun
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
push "sndbuf 524288"
push "rcvbuf 524288"

Конфиг клиента:
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote XXXXXXX 1195
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert cl.crt
key cl.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-GCM
connect-retry-max 25
verb 3
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288

UPD 08.07: Поднял SFTP мимо VPN - картина аналогична(

Нашёл причину - трассировка показала, что у провайдеров кривые маршруты, и на промежуточном провайдере теряются пакеты, все оказалось проще) сейчас решаю вопрос с провайдерами по перестроению маршрутов
